# How do you go about understanding/internalizing a fairly large Verilog design at say a new company you joined

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog

I have just started a job as a digital design engineer at a new company and I'm getting familiar with their designs. I've been reading verilog code and running simulation with ncsim and looking at the variables' waveforms in simvision and trying to understand the big picture. I wanted to know if there are any tips and tricks to digesting a hardware designs; any tools of the trade less known that will help me speed up with catching up and get contributing.

Comment: I've recently started using schematic tracer in simvsion and its been helpful. But the process is slow and I'm not sure if my employer has too much patience waiting for me to get familiarized at this pace.

Comment: don't worry about time to get familiarized. *Everyone* thinks they take too long to get familiarized.

Comment: Thanks @user253751, I was wondering if getting familiarized with the whole design is a bad approach, and I should just try and learn to operate locally? The way software designers are able to work on compartmentalized code. Probably thats an art in itself?

Comment: maybe start by looking at the design as a black box ... get familiar with the externals first ... then figure out if the internals can be thought of as smaller black boxes

Comment: @nebuchadnezzar_II i would say it's normal to understand the general ideas of the whole design, and the small details in the part where you are actually working. If you don't feel like you need to know something then don't waste your time on it. If you do, then do.

Comment: @All - On this occasion, I'll re-open the question as it is *not* opinion-based. The OP is asking for *experience-based* answers, from people who have "been there & done that". This type of question is allowed on Stack Exchange: See the 2nd half of [this page from the help center](/help/dont-ask) and [this official blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) which led to that help center page. In short: We only want good answers that you can back-up with experience. Other types of answers / guesses / rants etc. may be deleted. Let's see if anyone can help...

Comment: Requirements documents, design review artifacts, and detailed block diagrams are invaluable for trying to understand what a given design is supposed to do.

Comment: @nebuch Sometimes, internal documentation is good. But more often, I've found, mostly pretty spotty. A lot of it is carried in the heads of people working with you. So I tend to work outside inward and simultaneously from the deepest (smallest blocks) internals building from there, outward to see what the unique functional blocks are and how they couple together with commonly understood blocks towards more interesting and complex 'machinery' that is relied upon. It's burning the candle at both ends, so to speak. Working inward means learning application requirements, customer-related domain

Comment: @nebuch knowledge, and everything from there to the detailed physics of the transducers -- those things that translate from a physical reality to electronic signals and visa versa. I'll talk with the physicists and read papers they suggest, talk with the technical sales staff, and in some cases perform my own small-scale experimentation and log notes in a logbook. Working outward means identifying the obvious common blocks that describe the basics of any design (or learning those, if I'm missing some of them) and then also trying to pick out the simpler blocks that are novel to me and perhaps

Comment: @nebuch unique to the application space. I'll talk with other designers to get clues about where to look for the special bits that I need to study and gather up. This is a place where I can apply myself, efficiently, as the blocks are by definition simpler. From there, once those are acquired, I can work outward towards the application space by seeing how these simpler blocks are assembled into more complex functions. Eventually, this process joins up in the middle.

Comment: a 'fairly large' design means it has enough complexity to be worth trying to decompose it into specific levels, like OSI does for communications. People who know the whole system will flip between levels, looking at the timings of a particular building block, or the meaning of the whole application, without bothering to inform you of where they are. If it doesn't exist, then for your own documentation, draw a layered map of the whole system, and use it communicating with the others. It often takes a naive set of eyes to show the need for this sort of document.

Comment: @Neil_UK I've been in the situation where ***I*** was that naive set of eyes. In one such case, I found time (I didn't tell anyone that I was applying paid time for this purpose) to walk through the entire system and develop a full, layered data flow diagram of the system so that I could understand what I was looking at. When I showed it to the VP of technology there he was excited! He told me that he had borrowed from google searches and didn't really understand everything their team had coded up until looking at my diagram set. The company used it to train others, afterwards!

Comment: @jonk & Neil_UK thank you for your invaluable insights. I have direction now.